# Get the processes that are accessing a UDSocket

Tags: linux, command-line

> fuser - identify processes using files or sockets

How to use this function to know the process id's of the two processes that are accessing a file that is the fd for a udsocket?

I have tried:

```
fuser -m /tmp/.dn_usage
```

but that just gives me some numbers like

```
1328rce  1334rce  1335rce  1336rce  1338rce  1340rce  1341rce
```

which I am not sure how to use.

Ok. So i will rephrase my question.
How to get the processes that are accessing a unix domain socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should reread the man page ? All the fields are explained, the number before the letters is the PID (ie Process ID). You can add the `-v` flag for more information about the process.